# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un programa simple de calculo del cubo en uno de multiproceso? (Python)

Tags: python, proceso

Tengo un código simple con un bucle while que va pidiendo números para calcular el cubo de este hasta que escribas el número 0, con el cual, el programa parará:

```
e = 1

while(e != 0):
   
  print("Número para calcular")
  e = int(input())


  r = e * e * e

  print("El cubo de "+str(e)+" es: "+str(r))
```

He visto que he planteado mal la pregunta, he estado investigando un poco y he llegado a escribir este código:

```
import multiprocessing

def cub(e):

    r = e * e * e

    print("El cub de "+str(e)+" es: "+str(r))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = 1

    while(e != 0):

        print("Numero per fer el cub: ")
        e = int(input())
        
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=cub, args=(e,))
        
        p.start()
```

Veo que no me da errores y me da el resultado deseado. ¿Habría alguna manera de "mejorarlo" o ya cumple con lo deseado completamente?

Comment: Buenas Debianlu, ¿Qué has intentado hacer? SO está para ayudarte con problemas que te surjan. Primero investiga por tu cuenta y si lo necesitas vuelve con una duda mas especifica.

Comment: Buenas, Enrique, muchas gracias, he visto que había planteado mal la pregunta y he estado investigando un poco para editar la pregunta.

Comment: Deberías usar `Thread`, `Process` de manera interna mueve los datos con un socket y eso añade mucho coste de tiempo, aparte de eso es recomendable que tengas un candado separado para los hilos (para aligerar el uso del GIL)